# How compatible are SFPs really?

Tags: switch, sfp

How compatible are sfp modules between devices. For example, am I likely to be able to plug [something like this](http://www.cdwg.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1278641) into a cisco, hp, or other switch with mini gbic ports?

Comment: Many telecom vendors has announced that their products are 100% compatible with the original brand, which may be quite confused for the buyers. You should turn to a reliable OEM vendor and make sure its compatibility.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have been asked the question many times in my technical support role at Advance Technology. If a device requires coded SFP modules (i.e. Cisco / HP) then you need either the OEM module or a compatible version.
If the device does not require coded SFP (i.e. Netgear) then you can use any SFP, even a Cisco.

Please see this document regarding the compatibility of SFP's and also a FAQ I put together in an attempt to straighten out some of the confusion on this topic.

http://knowledge.advance.technology/information-why-choose-advance-compatible-transceivers/

Comment: Actually, on Cisco gear you can disable the need for coded SFPs. Good luck getting support in that config, but you can do it.

Comment: n.b On Cisco platforms the command "service unsupported-transceiver" is generally available in NxOS and IOS versions.  The command won't autocomplete and, as is implied, it is unsupported but allows the use of 3rd party optics.

Comment: It allows it but not all will work.