# Do 3Com switches support generic SFPs?

Tags: switch, fiber, 3com, sfp

I have a 4200 series switch with an empty sfp port, and existing unused fiber run (62.5nm multimode) to another building that I hope to bring up, with a 1000base-SX connection on the other end.  Unfortunately I'm having trouble finding a 3Com branded sfp for it via my usual sources, and I'm wondering if the switch will support a generic sfp.

Based on a [prior question](https://serverfault.com/questions/195104/how-compatible-are-sfps-really) I know that the hardware should be capable, but it will come down to whether or not 3com chose to lock down their switches to only work with 3Com SFPs. I can't find any documentation on this - does anyone know whether the 3Com switch is likely to work with an off-brand sfp?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if a HP vendor has one, since 3Com is now HP?

Answer (score 1):

We have a few working - never had an issue in the past.
We have used some ACP ones in the past   MFG Part # 3CSFP91AOK

A quick Froogle.com search shows them readily available for under $60